Issues with a time-dependent market price of risk
I have a time-dependent market price of risk of an asset as:
$$ \lambda(t) = \frac{\mu(t)-r(t)}{(T-t)\sigma}
$$
where $t$ is the current time and $T$ is a constant maturity time of an asset.
Here, $\mu(t)$ is the drift of the asset, $r(t)$ is the risk free rate and $\sigma(T-t)$ is basically the time-dependent volatility of the asset.
However, as you can see, at $t=T$, the market price of risk is undefined because of the denominator. In my calculations, I need the market price of risk to be of this form or similar. Hence, do you have any input on how I can keep a similar form off $\lambda$ but still have it defined and continuous at the maturity time. I'm a bit stuck with this and thus, any insight/feedback would be greatly appreciated!

I would assume that technically, $\mu$ and $r$ should be made a function of time, as well.

Yes they are. I will edit my post to reflect that.

I think there are too many omitted details in this question. What are you using the MPR for? Are there any constraints on the functional form of your MPR?

I need it to find the optimal investment position of this asset. The constraints are that the MPR should somehow satisfy the progressive measurability condition, which it does not because it is not continuous at t=T.

Given the updated formula, I guess you do not have a problem as long as $\lim_{t\to T}\frac{\mu(t)-r(t)}{(T-t)\sigma}$ exists, no? I would even assume that - for this problem to make economical sense - you should see $\lim_{t\to T} \mu(t)=r(T)$ and hence $\lim_{t\to T}\lambda(t)=0$

Oh I see. However, in my case $\lim_{t \to T} \lambda(t) = f(T)$. It's because both my $\mu(t)$ and $r(t)$ are stochastic rates. Does the limit above still make economic sense?

Even then, IMHO, $f(T)$ must tend to zero as $\sigma$ tends to zero: No risk, no return!
